# Plugin will sort users by usermeta

Tags: query, wpdb, user-meta, buddypress

As I refine my most popular plugin it will store a special number decoded from the user's birth date, which is an extended BuddyPress field in `bp_xprofile_data`. All users get a number between 1 and 260, and I will assemble a list of BuddyPress users based on this number.

It seems there's at least two established methods of storing extended user data with the `usermeta` table. There are 4 possible methods I can imagine:

1. Use the BuddyPress `bp_xprofile_data` table
2. Use the `usermeta` table
3. Add a field to the `wp_users` table so that I can get `user_id`
   with the "fastest PHP in the west"
4. Create a fresh new table for my awesome plugin

I want code that is efficient with resources of course, as there's gunna be lot's 'o doggies to corral.

Is the recommended method to insert the number into the `usermeta`, and retrieve it with a query, something like this?

```
$users_by_kin = "SELECT * 
    FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta 
    WHERE meta_key='kin_id' 
    AND meta_value='$kin_id'"
```

Which method is considered best WP Practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want best practices of the options you listed use the user meta table.

Adding a column to the users table would be the worst thing you could do - messing with table structure of default WP tables is a no-no.

The other two options would fall somewhere in between - with adding your own table being least preferred.

But why don't you use the WP_User_Query class?

```
 $user_by_kin = new WP_User_Query( 
    array( 
        'meta_key' => 'kin_id', 
        'meta_value' => $kin_id, 
        'meta_compare' => '=' 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

As I understand it, I would add the metadata in this way...

$user_id = 2;
$kin_id = 139;
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'kin_id', $awesome_level);

Comment: I think that based on you showed in your original query, it would be add_user_meta( $user_id, 'kin_id', $kin_id);